# Ionic: unable to use `resume` and `pause` in ios app

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*.      I want to clear `window.localStorage` when app is close or open in background.    For this i have tried below code within `.run()` in app.js

```
 $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function() {
                  window.localStorage.clear();
                   });

$ionicPlatform.on('pause', function() {
                  window.localStorage.clear();
                   });
```

But using this code my App get stuck only splash screen display ,    i am unable to proceed further.

Please help me.

Comment: *my App get stuck only splash screen display* that is a dead giveaway that there's a syntax error somewhere in the code. Please double check it. Check in the Safari debugger with phone plugged in and examine the console.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. i have checked there is no syntax error if i remove resume and pause event from the app, it  running as expected.

Comment: You have declared `$IonicPlatform` in the header of the controller?

Comment: yes i have declared `$IonicPlatform` in the header .